# Power Query - Creating a custom column list from an existing list with a logic check

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm currently trying to use Power Query to create a new custom column that will return a list (eventually so I can count the number of True instances). I have gotten to this

```
=Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "53 Foot Containers Part 2", each List.Transform( [Raw Commodity Description_List],  each Text.Contains( [Raw Commodity Description_List], "53")))
```

The custom column creates the correct number of items in the list but unfortunately, each item within the list is an error with the following error message; "Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Text."

An example of the list in the Commodity Description_List is;

```
EMPTY CYLINDERS

53 CONTAINERS; 40 CONTAINER; 45 CONTAINER; 53 CONTAINER

20 CONTAINERS; 40 CONTAINER
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What is expected result for each row? Is example provided example just one column delimited by semicolon?

Comment: Hi @MichalPalko, what I provided was an example of the column. In essence the column [Raw Commodity Description_List] contains a list of descriptors in text of values with the semicolon denoting each item within the list. What I have provided is an example of 3 rows in that column. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

your data is in a list in each cell of the row

To count the number of instances of **53** in that list on each row, use

```
 = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "53 Foot Containers Part 2", each List.Sum(List.Transform([Raw Commodity Description_List], each if Text.Contains(_,"53") then 1 else 0)))
```

Comment: Hi @horseyride! Thank you so much! I was trying to achieve the former. I tried what you recommended and I get an error 

Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text.

Comment: post an image showing your source data in powerquery right before the step you want to do. Somewhere we are mixing types and it is hard to tell what you were starting with  . Something similar to https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnXnn.png

Comment: Hi @horsyride! Thank you very much for your help

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PNQU4Pum7LXDmEkNXBe-B4cXPAHS27n3/view?usp=sharing

This is a link to the image for the actual columns and I've included the a sample of the items within the list

Comment: it wants me to request access to your google drive. Not doing that. Please paste image in publicly accessible location like uploading into your original question by editing it

Comment: My apologies, got myself a imgur account and here you go
https://imgur.com/m07EUY3

Comment: Ah, its in a list on each row. See top of edited answer.

Comment: it works perfectly now!

Could I ask what the main difference between the former solution and the latest one is? Also, is my understanding of the formula correct; List.Transform will go through each item within the list and replace anything containing "53" with 1 if not it will be 0 and the List.Sum will add up the value of the list?

Comment: The last solution assumed the data cell was text the new one recognizes it is a list   And your understanding of the formula is right